# error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_gravity' with value 'start')

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I would like to implement a navigation drawer but in my xml file 
I get this error:

error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_gravity' with value 
 'start').

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->


<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".NeueNotizActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDocuTitleNewDocu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/Docu.title" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="410dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btSaveNewDocu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btAbortNewDocu"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:onClick="speichern"
    android:text="@string/Docu.save"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />



</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#F3F3F4"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I hope you can help.
When I delete this: android:layout_gravity="start" then the menu do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start is actually valid: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity

However I've only seen it used when account for languages that read right to left, otherwise use left like the following :

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how to use these values??

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what minSdkVersion you're targetting (in your AndroidManifest), compile your project with Android 4.